# Is there any way to achieve something like `echo $a | xargs sh -c a="89"` in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a line in .bashrc:

```
alias bc=~/SCRIPT/bcc.sh
```

bcc.sh is a file with one string:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$@" | bc -l
```

Is there a way to write this command in .bashrc directly, without a supplementary file?

Comment: You could write a bash *function*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a function instead of an alias.

```
bc() {
    command bc -l <<< "$@"
}
```

`command` ensures the function doesn't call itself recursively. `<<< "$@"` is a nice alternative to `echo "$@" |` that avoids the overhead of a pipeline.